# Update child selects

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to make a simple dynamic form with 3 selects.

My problem is that the options of child selects should be filled based on option selected in parent select.

Here is my code:

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
     return {
         value: 'select'
     }
 },
 change: function(event){
     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 },
 render: function(){
    return(
      React.createElement(
  'div',
  {  },
  React.createElement(
    'select',
    { id: this.props.id,
      onChange: this.change,
      value: this.state.value
     },
     React.createElement("option", null, "Yes"),
     React.createElement("option", null, "No"),
    this.props.title
  ),
  React.createElement(
    'select',
    { id: this.props.id,
      onChange: this.change,
      value: this.state.value
     },
     React.createElement("option", null, "Author1"),
     React.createElement("option", null, "Author2"),
    this.props.title
  ),
  React.createElement(
    'select',
    { id: this.props.id,
      onChange: this.change,
      value: this.state.value
     },
     React.createElement("option", null, "Book1"),
     React.createElement("option", null, "Book2"),
    this.props.title
  )
));
 }
});
```

So if we select Yes, we have 2 authors, and if we select author1 - we can select only book1.

In case we select author2, we can select only book2 but not book1. If we select No, we cannot select any authors or books. I believe there should be something with states, but I still cannot get the point from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to break it down into a flow of components than managing everything in a complex state machine in a single component.

1. You can extract the Author element logic to a new component. If the first select has a 'Yes', you render the Author component, otherwise not.
2. In the Author component, you should manage the author selected as a state and pass in that state to the Book component as a prop.
3. In the Book component, you can render the select menu options as per the author received in the props.
4. You'll also have to use `componentWillReceiveProps` in Book component to keep track of changing props.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Could you please provide some code for example. I am not quite familiar with states((

Comment: https://github.com/rajzshkr/componentWillReceiveProps  -  this helped with the problem

Answer (score 0):

I will explain with code. You could do the following. You could have 3 boolean states, one would be assigned to the select list of authors and other 2 to the individual option values(book1, book2). Based on what the users selects in the list- Yes or No.
Consider the following code.
Onchange handler of Yes/No select list

```
             If(event.target.value=="Yes")
             {
               this.setState({AuthorsSelectable:true,
               book1Selectable:true,
               book2Selectable:true
               });

            }
            else{
                this.setState({AuthorsSelectable:false,
                 book1Selectable:false,
                 book2Selectable:false
          });

            }
```

Now you would in the onchange handler of Author1/Author2 list

```
             if(event.target.value="Author1"){

            this.setState({book1Selectable:true,
            book2Selectable:false
            });

            }
         else{

          this.setState({

            book1Selectable:false.
            book2Selectable:true
          });
```

Hope this helps.